# Handling regular expression with quantities, units and additional information

Tags: regex, string, pcre

I have a regular expression to match for any numbers at the beginning of a string:

`^(0|[1-9]\d*)?(\.\d+)?(?<=\d)`

This works fine, but sometimes there is no number in front.

For example those strings:

```
a few of X
few X
X (or simply X)
```

Then of course I have no match. But there should be one, because I want to handle these types of string:

```
1 tbps olive oil
0.1 l olive oil, 
1.5 tomatoes, dried
2 red tomatoes (cutted)
tomatoes, cutted (something else)
```

So I want to have in my regular expression those groups:

- quantity like 1 or 0.1 , if there is one
- the unit like l or tbps, if there is one
- the "thing" like "tomatoes" or "red tomatoes"
- if there is a comma or starting "(", everything after the comma or everything starting with "(" in one reg ex group

How do I need to extend my regular expression?

Comment: Is the intent of the regex to detect a line which has an ingredient?

Comment: The requirements are not precise, that is why currently, any suggestion would be very clumsy or imprecise. Try `^(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:\h*(tbps|[kdm]?l|[kdm]?gr?))?(?:\h+|^)(\w+(?:\h+\w+)*)(?:\h*(?:,\h*)?(.*))?$` ([demo](https://regex101.com/r/C0GlJn/1)).

Comment: How to improve a [tag:regex] question: Add a tag specifying the language or tool.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Works great, but I have an issue with umlauts, see https://regex101.com/r/5DRgU7/1

Comment: No problem, the demo is in PHP/PCRE, so `/u` flag fixes it, see https://regex101.com/r/5DRgU7/2

Comment: @AndrewMorton Yes, I need to extract the various string groups of such a line of text.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew One more thing. The characters - and / are not handled properply, see https://regex101.com/r/GbJxUY/1

Comment: @Tim Perhaps a regex will only get you some of the way there, such as getting some numeric quantity (which could be a fraction like 2 1/2), and the following string. Then, if the line started with digits, examine the next item to see if it could be units (tbsp, ml, g, etc.). And hope you don't get an item like "Chopped tomatoes (1/2 can)".

Comment: Ok, what about https://regex101.com/r/GbJxUY/2?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew So great, thanks a lot. I created a new one with two more test strings https://regex101.com/r/Uu20NB/1 If sth. is in front of the quantity, it does not match, i.e. 'ca. 30 tbps Test' and I saw for '5 tbps Test string (additional info)' the third group is "Test string " which is not trimmed at the end.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew For the ca. in front, I added this: ([a-zA-Z.:]*)?(?:\h+|^) Is this correct? Or how can I do this in a better way?

Comment: Tim, you should understand one thing: regular expressions are not intelligent. They just match specific characters in specific order and in specific context. If you cannot define exact rules for the pattern, it is impossible to write the right regex. I cannot tell you what the better way is because I do not know what way it is good. I deduced a couple of patterns from your sample strings, that is all I could do. You have your data, you must come up with the requirements. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Uu20NB/2) if you need to exclude `ca.` from  Group 1 value.

Comment: Tim, does the latest demo work for you?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew It is working great, thank you very much! There is one special case if I have for a quantity a from-to quantity, i.e. "1-2 tbps Test". Is it possible to handle? I think I need two capturing groups, so that I have the first and the second number, it could be also a decimal value, separated. Also it could be "1-2" or with with white spaces "1 - 2".

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/Uu20NB/3

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew Thanks, but the two numbers are not separated in this case and the "ca." is not working anymore - it is not captured in a group, see https://regex101.com/r/XG1Jb8/1

Comment: So, do you want https://regex101.com/r/XG1Jb8/2 then?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew With the latest one, "few salt" is not working anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can use

```php
^(?:(ca\.)\h*)?(?:(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?)?(?:\h*(wenig|tbps|[kdm]?l|[kdm]?gr?))?(?:\h+|^)([^,(\n\r]*)(?:\h*(?:,\h*)?(.*))?$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5ZkWVu/2). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:(ca\.)\h*)?` - an optional non-capturing grop matching and capturing `ca.` into Group 1 and then matching zero or more horizontal whitespaces
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 2: one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
  - `(?:\s*-\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` - an optional sequence of

    - `\s*-\s*` - a hyphen enclosed with zero or more whitespaces
    - `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)` - Group 3: one or more digits and then an optional occurrence of a `.` and one or more digits
- `)?` - end of the group, match one or zero times (optional)
- `(?:\h*(wenig|tbps|[kdm]?l|[kdm]?gr?))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(wenig|tbps|[kdm]?l|[kdm]?gr?)` - Group 4: `wenig`, `tbps`,`kl`, `dl`, `ml` or `l`, or `k`, `d`, `m` followed with `g` and an optional `r`
- `(?:\h+|^)` - either one or more horizontal whitespaces or start of string
- `([^,(\n\r]*)` - Group 5: zero or more chars other than `,`, `(` and CR/LF
- `(?:\h*(?:,\h*)?(.*))?` - an optional sequence of

  - `\h*` - zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(?:,\h*)?` - an optional sequence of `,` and zero or more horizontal whitespaces
  - `(.*)` - Group 6: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `$` - end of string.

If you do not deal with multiline texts, you may remove `\r\n` from the negated character class(es) and use `\s` instead of `\h`.

Comment: Works great, but it is not possible anymore, that you have "few pepper" or "tomatoes, cutted", a string without a number, see https://regex101.com/r/5ZkWVu/1

Comment: @Tim Sorry, lost an optional group when editing the pattern. `(\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:\s*-\s*(\d+(?:\.\d+)?))?` should have been wrapped with a non-capturing optional group.